# Getting error trying to insert ip address as string in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector-python, insert-statement

what is wrong with my code,

```
with connect_db() as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    stmt = """INSERT INTO ip_records ip_address VALUES (%s)"""
    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt, (ip))
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print err
        return
```

I am trying to insert ip address as string to mysql table. But I am getting this error:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ip_address VALUES (192.168.11.111)' at line 1
```

Comment: Should that be `(ip_address)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `""` for the IP to be considered a string:

```py
with connect_db() as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    stmt = """INSERT INTO ip_records (ip_address) VALUES (%s)"""
    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt, (ip,))
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print err
        return
```

**EDIT**
You also need a coma to pass parameters as tuple `(ip,)`instead of `(ip)`

The actual errors were a syntax error (for not having brackets around `(ip_address)` and a python arguments error for not having the coma on the tuple `(ip,)`.

The quotes were not necessary.

Comment: then I get error: `ValueError: Could not process parameters`

Comment: and also include the brackets

Comment: you need a coma after `ip` inside the brackets > `cursor.execute(stmt, (ip,))`

Comment: You don't need quotes inside the SQL around a parameter marker.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to add](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) brackets around `ip_address` or remove it.

Comment: then I get error : `ValueError: Could not process parameters`

Comment: One step further I'd assume. How is the data type of `ip_address` defined and what value is inserted?

Comment: I'm asking about the database schema.

Comment: `ip_address` is a string type in mysql db.